# windows batch commands execution issue file being used by another process

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to compress a file using my Batch program, But i am stuck with below issue, This is a server log file which always gets data populated by server and we need to keep it running. No other way, I need to compress this file while it is being used. I want to force execute this, Please suggest me a solution.

Weblogic server does not facilitate it for ".out" files, It is available only for ".log" file. Our current issue is to compress this .out file

The utility i am calling the script is 
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip NewArchive.zip new_ManagedServer_1.out

```
> 7-Zip [64] 16.04 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-10-04
> 
> Scanning the drive: 1 file, 25972 bytes (26 KiB)
> 
> Creating archive:
> C:\Oracle\Middleware12c\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\new_ManagedServer_1\logs\new_ManagedServer_1-07252017-223920.zip
> 
> Items to compress: 1
> 
> 
> WARNING: The process cannot access the file because it is being used
> by another process.
> C:\Oracle\Middleware12c\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\new_ManagedServer_1\logs\new_ManagedServer_1.out
> 
> 
> Files read from disk: 1 Archive size: 22 bytes (1 KiB)
> 
> WARNINGS for files:
> 
> C:\Oracle\Middleware12c\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\new_ManagedServer_1\logs\new_ManagedServer_1.out
> : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by
> another process.
> ---------------- WARNING: Cannot open 1 file The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not do this while the file is in use

you should try to configure your oracle Middleware to rotate the outfile (create new file every hour or day) so it is no longer accessed, than you can zip the old file.

Comment: Unfortunately, Weblogic server does not facilitate it for ".out" files, It is available only for ".log" file. Our current issue is to compress this .out file.

Comment: check this http://robin4444.blogspot.de/2011/11/rotate-out-log-files.html

Comment: This needs to be done in Windows Environment, the solution #2 "unix LogRotate" utility we are already familiar with in one of our environment, We are using it. And secondly the reason for not redirecting to server.log file is cause we mostly refer to .out log for any errors in the first place, So for us it is a must have thing.

Comment: only windows native way I can think of is to stop the application service or program, then compress the out file, create a new empty out file and restart the application. task scheduler could do this after hours.

Comment: Umm, Sadly.... , As I mentioned earlier this will be applied to production scenarios in future and we cannot afford to stop the server to achive this Stephan

Comment: I'm more the windows guy than oracle, but I don't think that there is a way that you can take the file while accessed without killing the process. maybe you should take this to an oracle forum